# Removing bot tweets when using Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

#### Is there a way to remove bot tweets (or at least minimize it) when using Twitter API ?

Especially, I would like to know if it is possible to do that from the query.
But, I am open to any kind of solution.

**My research :**

I found that adding `-is:nullcast -bio:bot -bio_name:bot -bio_location:bot -bio:TwitterBot -bio_name:TwitterBot -bio_location:TwitterBot` at the end of a query minimize the amount of bot tweets received. But I still have a lot of bot tweets.